# Installing GIT server on CentOS 6.7

Tags: git, centos6, smart-http

We have a private server where our code will reside on. We want to use GIT as our source code management. We don't want to host our code on GITHub and that's why we would like to have a private GIT server running.

Our problem is not with installing GIT per say, it's with setting up user access. Our developers won't have SSH access to the server so we want to setup SMART HTTP ACCESS on GIT. This would prompt user credentials whenever a developer wants to pull something or push something. We can't seem to find a clear-cut instructions on how to do that successfully.

Anyone out there with a link or documentation that's clean enough to help us setup this correctly?

Comment: @VonC That link seems very much unrelated to this question.

Comment: @VonC I'm not sure this is what we're looking for. Are you sure about the link?

Comment: @Brams Sorry for the mix-up (I deleted the comment). I was thinking about https://github.com/gogits/gogs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GitLab for your purpose. It's a open source and scalable solution. You can use Community edition.

Even stack overflow uses it.

GitLab's official guide on how to install GitLab on CentOS 6: https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#centos6

There's one more solution to this 
checkout:  https://bitbucket.org/ it's same as gitlab with more advance UI and features.

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own git server in your serve computer . you dont need to use third party websites

install git in server and create users , then install git in your terminal pc create an rsa public key at attached it in the user git in the server see the tutorial link below

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDH3vivx3n4